# How to create stacked progress bar chart with JS to display on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I am looking for this solution. I would like to know how to recreate this style of the stacked bar chart.
I will use this to indicate the status of the machinery during the day. so the color can be used more than once like in the picture.

[Show picture of Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4HBZ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to use any library -

Chart.js is good one that I have used and they do support stacked-bar graph

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/samples/bar/stacked.html

They have a good document also on how to use it.

Comment: I've tried to make one with those libraries. But I still cannot find a way to create a stacked horizontal bar chart that can show the status of the machine according to time continuously. and with the libraries, I can't find a way to make it show the same color that indicates the status (like "Running","Stopped","Maintanance") which will have to show the same color multiple times.